# Jest complains when using web3.eth - open handle error

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ethereum, web3js

I'm getting the following error:

> Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

When executing a simple test like this

```
var currentProvider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/XXXXXXXXX');
var web3 = new Web3(currentProvider);

const info = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest')
expect(info.gasLimit).toBeGreaterThan(0)
```

The error points to getBlock

```
const info = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest')
```

I'm not understanding what the problem is and how to handle this?

Comment: I've encountered the same problem with `web3.eth.getTransactionCount()`, and I suspect this has the same root cause. Have you figured out something?